# Are you upgrading to Visual Studio 2010 or are you forced to stay with 2008 (or worse)

Tags: visual-studio

We are on VS 2008 at the moment and it's very hard to convince management that we should move to 2010 (we have just recently upgraded to 2008...).

I wonder if there are many of you with the same problem at the moment, or maybe you had a similar situation and managed to push the change in your organization somehow? I'd be happy to read some ideas of how you did it.

Comment: Why do I need to upgrade? because I want to use new features.
Why do I need to know how others with similar problem approached management? because I run out of ideas and want to know if management in my company is exceptionally stubborn or not.

Comment: johny, if your management is not willing to provide you, the technician, with the proper tools, quit your job ! TODAY

Comment: That statement might have made sense years ago when the economy was so good.  Unless your micro-economy is still booming, I'd say advice like that is outdated at best and irresponsible at worst.

Comment: I'd love to quit and go somewhere else anyway, but just wonder how popular is VS2010. Is it worth to skill up in .net 4/latest tools or is it still too early and there won't be much demand for these skills for some time? Do you know any official stats on how many companies are still using 2008? I mean, we're still using WinForms here (just started a new project) and won't be doing fancy wpf stuff in the nearest future..

Answer (score 0):

If it's hard to convince, this may be an indication that there is no enought value in your upgrade project than you thought.

Or, you are trying to convince them with wrong features.

Upgrading to VS2010 will increase your productivity, and therefore decrease their costs.

New debugging and testing features justify, alone, the upgrade.

Let's see if your management are smart enough to both make your happy and decrease their costs ;)

More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547188.aspx